# What's a good naming convention for methods that take conditional action?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

Let's say I have a method, `Foo()`. There are only certain times when `Foo()` is appropriate, as determined by the method `ShouldFooNow()`. However, there are many times when the program must consider if `Foo()` is appropriate at this time. So instead of writing:

```
if ShouldFooNow():
   Foo()
```

everywhere, I just make that into one function:

```
def __name():
    if ShouldFooNow():
       Foo()
```

What would be a good name for this method? I'm having a hard time coming up with a good convention. `IfNecessaryFoo()` is awkward, particularly if `Foo()` has a longer name. `DoFooIfShould()`? Even more awkward.

What would be a better name style?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you're pretty close. Put the action/intent at the head of the method name, for easier alphabetic searching.  If I were writing something like that, I'd consider

```
FooIfNecessary()
FooIfRequired()
```

Say, for instance,

```
ElevatePermissionsIfNecessary()
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `EnsureFoo()`.

For example, the method `EnsurePermissions()` will take the appropriate action if needed. If the permissions are already correct, the method won't do anything.

Comment: "_ensure_ carries the meaning of making sure that something is taken care of" is also suggested by an [answer in Software Engineering: language agnostic - Naming a "do X if needed" method](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/161755/353999).

Answer (score 3):

I've recently started using the convention:

```
FooIf(args, bool);
```

Where args are any arguments that the method takes and bool is either expecting a boolean value or a Func of some kind that resolves to a boolean.  Then, within that method, I check the bool and run the logic.  Keeps such assertions down to one line and looks clean to me.

Example in my C# code for logging:

```
public void WarnIf<T>(T value, string message, Func<T, bool> isTrue)
{
  if (isTrue(value)) _log.Warn(message);
}
```

Then I would call it with something like:

```
WarnIf(someObject, "This is a warning message to be logged.", s => s.SomeCondition == true);
```

(That caller may not be correct, but you get the idea... I don't have the code in front of me right now.)

Comment: Is that really how you would call `WarnIf()?` Wheres's the first arg?

Comment: Edited.  I missed that one in a hurry.  Got too used to the extension methods I've been writing all day :)

Comment: You don't need `== true`.

Answer (score 2):

Michael Petrotta's answer (`IfNecessary` or `IfRequired` suffix) is good, but I prefer a shorter alternative: `IfNeeded`.

```
ElevatePermissionsIfNeeded()
```

And if you want something even shorter I would consider a prefix like `May` or `Might`:

```
MayElevatePermissions()
MightElevatePermissions()
```

Comment: The issue with the prefix way is that method names are usually verbs that explicitly indicate the action, but in this case it sounds as if we were indicating a side effect; so I know `MayElevatePermissions` may elevate permissions, but is that the primary action, or just a side effect? Or it may also sound as a question with a `bool` return type, which doesn't actually perform an action, in the vein of `Can-`, `Is-`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what's wrong with the original code:

```
if shouldFoo():
  Foo();
```

is perfectly clear IMHO.

Not just that, but it clearly separates concerns of deciding about doing the action, vs the action itself.

Another option for a similar question with a slightly different approach to avoiding the postfix:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/161754/262009