# Run method when multiple conditions fulfilled

Tags: java

I'm currently creating a java programm where I want to run a method, after two conditions are fulfilled. So right when both conditions are occuring, the method should be called. The only way I can think of handling it is as I added it below, but it doesn't seem like the optimal way to do so.

Here no matter if `method1` or `method2` is called first, the following method is checking if the other condition is already fulfilledand then runs the method. Since there might be methods that depend on more conditions then two, are there more clearer way to handle it?

My example:

```
public class Test() {

    private boolean condition1 = false;
    private boolean condition2 = false;

    public void method1(){
        condition1 = true;
        if(condition2){
            run();
        }
    }

    public void method2(){
        condition2 = true;
        if(condition1){
            run();
        }
    }    

    public void run(){
        //Is run when both conditions are true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Since there might be methods that depend on more conditions then two*

As per the statement above I guess I can assume you might have more than two conditions, and perhaps multiple combinations? In that case you wouldn't want to verify the conditions in your `run` method.

You could have a dedicated method applying the required conditions as needed, something like this:

```
public void runIfTheConditionsAreMet() {
    if(condition1 && condition2) {
        run();
    }
}
```

This way you would have a dedicated method to check for the conditions and call your `run` method only when necessary, without repeating code in your `method1`,  `method2`, and you would have a place you could document the conditions (if necessary).

Your code would look a little bit cleaner, as below:

```
public void method1(){
    condition1 = true;
    runIfTheConditionsAreMet();
}

public void method2(){
    condition2 = true;
    runIfTheConditionsAreMet();
}
```

Ps. Even if you don't intend to have more conditions I think this solution would fit your needs.

Comment: Okay, thank you that seems like a similar but good way too. So do you think it's a common way to handle condition based method calls like that?

Comment: It's not that common because not everybody will have this same scenario. For normal cases people would simply use a method like "public boolean method xx {return condition1 && condition2;}", or even what you did. But for your case, you would have to repeat the condition check for both your "method1" and "method2", which would make maintenance more difficult, and it's not DRY (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
 friendly.

Comment: Here are some discussions about using methods like the one I used: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/367933/put-conditional-logic-inside-method-for-dry-or-keep-it-outside-for-readability, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160261/whats-a-good-naming-convention-for-methods-that-take-conditional-action?rq=1

Comment: Here is a link on decomposing conditional statements, to show why it's nice having methods to check conditions instead of having standard "ifs" with multiple conditions: https://refactoring.guru/decompose-conditional

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention.. I've seen this in the real world and I've used it myself.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I were to open up this code, and have to understand it, I would have a much easier time if I saw something more like this:

```
public void run(){
    if(condition1 && condition2){
        // Now run the important code
    }
}
```

Whatever calls were made to method1 and method2 before would be changed to calls to run(). This seems much more intuitive to me, instead of spreading the check out between two methods, either one of which may execute run().

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).